# iOS Swift centralManager didConntectPeripheral never gets called

Tags: ios, swift3, bluetooth

I am new to both Bluetooth and Swift and right now, I am trying to simply connect to a Bluetooth device (Arduino HM-10) and acquire the services. The problem that I am having is that after I connect to the device, centralManager didConnectPeripheral method is never being called. Here is my code

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth

class ViewController: UIViewController, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {

    var manager:CBCentralManager!
    var peripheral:CBPeripheral!


    let BubbleWallBluetoothName = "TestBluetooth"
    let BEAN_SCRATCH_UUID =
        CBUUID(string: "a495ff21-c5b1-4b44-b512-1370f02d74de")
    let BEAN_SERVICE_UUID =
        CBUUID(string: "a495ff20-c5b1-4b44-b512-1370f02d74de")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        manager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil)
    }

    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager){

        switch (central.state)
        {
        case . unsupported:
            print("BLE is unsupported")
        case.unauthorized:
            print("BLE is unauthorised")
        case.unknown:
            print("BLE is unknown")
        case.resetting:
            print("BLE is resetting")
        case.poweredOff:
            print("BLE is powered off")
        case.poweredOn:
            print("BLE is powered on")
            central.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: nil)
        }

    }

    func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
        print("Found Device " + peripheral.name!)


        let device = (advertisementData as NSDictionary).object(forKey: CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey) as? NSString

        if (device?.contains(BubbleWallBluetoothName) == true) {
            self.manager.stopScan()

            self.peripheral = peripheral

            self.peripheral.delegate = self

            manager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
        }
    }


    //This function never gets called
    func centralManager(central: CBCentralManager, didConnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
        print("We are connected to BT");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I managed to make it work by replacing the last method with

```
func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
        peripheral.discoverServices(nil)
        print("We are connected to BT");
    }
```